# Как вывести имена бесед в ВК Python(vk_api)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Как можно вывести имена бесед из **ВК** используя библиотеку в **python**  `vk_api`

```
import vk_api 

session = vk_api.VkApi(token="my_token")
vk = session.get_api()

response = vk.messages.getConversations(filter='all', count=200)
```

Я знаю что есть JSON схема в которой вроде бы есть ключ title, но как в от туда извлечь имя бесед?